# how use the struts2 jquerytheme in standard struts tags

Tags: struts2, struts2-jquery

I used `<sj:head jquerytheme="blitzer" />` to apply blitzer theme and it works for `<sj:* >` tags; how to use the same theme in standard struts tags? (e.g. in `<s:a>`)

Comment: What you expect to jQuery theme will do with `<s:a>` tag?

Comment: e.g. I'd like `<s:submit>` to have the same look as `<sj:submit>`

Comment: You can look at rendered HTML and copy it for specific submit or modify template for `<s:submit>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think all your elements inherits the `theme` that you specified with `<sj:head jquerytheme="blitzer" />`.

Comment: @AleksandrM So can you use a different `theme` for elements in a page except using `cssClass` and `cssStyle`.

Comment: Themes are not the CSS. http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/themes-and-templates.html.

Comment: @AleksandrM Read the question very well, the `theme` the question is referring to is different from the `theme` you are pointing to.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But from your answer it seemed that you don't understand difference between Struts2 tags/themes and jQuery tags/themes.

Comment: @UchennaNwanyanwu I'm with Alexsandr; the jQuery UI themes are completely separate from anything in the default S2 tags. jQuery UI builds up its own DOM, dynamically, while S2 UI elements use the S2 templates.

Comment: @DaveNewton I think there is a misunderstanding here. The point i was trying to prove is that struts 2 and jquery themes do different things altogether which you have rightly emphasized. I don't think that the user that asked the question actually understand this difference hence the question. Maybe i should have pointed this out in the answer.

Comment: @UchennaNwanyanwu But tags like `<s:a>`, which *isn't* a jQuery tag, *don't* "inherit" anything relating to the jQuery UI theme.

Comment: @DaveNewton If i have done something like `<sj:head jquerytheme="redmond" />` and `<s:a>` in my page, what will happen to the look and feel of the link button. Will it not inherit the properties of the `redmond` theme at least its blue color. That's what i meant by `inherit` which i think the initial question wanted to alter.

Comment: @UchennaNwanyanwu AFAIK it wouldn't do anything, because the jQuery UI stylesheets, DOM elements, etc. are 100% separate from anything the S2 tags create. The CSS class/etc. names have nothing to do with each other. I'd need to double-check for sure, but I don't really see how this would work unless there's complete *S2* theme/template replacements that use the jQuery UI CSS class names etc, and I don't see any of that in the plugin with a cursory glance.